# State is unchanged from within a function returned by a hook

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I'm playing around with React and Canvas. I wanna animate the movement of a square through `requestAnimationFrame`. So I made the main component to handle canvas element and update of square's position:

```
function App() {
    let canvas = useRef()
    let square = useSquare(WIDTH / 2, HEIGHT, 2)
    let update = () => {
        square.update()
        requestAnimationFrame(update)
    }
    useEffect(update, [])
    return <>
        <canvas ref={canvas} width={WIDTH} height={HEIGHT} />
        <Renderer.Provider value={() => ref.canvas.getContext("2d")}>
            <Square {...square} />
        </Renderer.Provider>
    </>
}
```

The `Square` is a component but it doesn't return JSX. It runs drawing oprations at `useEffect`:

```
function Square({ x, y }) {
    let getContext = useContext(Renderer)
    useEffect(() => {
        let ctx = getContext()
        ctx.fillStyle = "#000"
        ctx.fillRect(x, y, 10, 10)
    }, [x, y])
    return null;
}
```

And I wanna use a hook to encapsulate state and behavior of the square:

```
function useSquare(init_x, init_y) {
    let [x, set_x] = useState(init_x)
    let [y, set_y] = useState(init_y)
    let [vx, set_vx] = useState(10)
    let [vy, set_vy] = useState(-5)
    let update = () => {
        set_x(prev_x => prev_x + vx)
        set_y(prev_y => prev_y + vy)
        if (x <= 0 || x >= WIDTH) set_vx(prev_vx => -prev_vx)
        else if (y <= 0 || y >= HEIGHT) set_vy(prev_vy => -prev_vy)
    }
    return { update, x, y }
}
```

Seems reasonable to me. However, it doesn't work as expected. Square is moving, but it doesn't respond to collisions with the viewport borders.

If I put `console.log(x, y)` into either of `update` functions, I can see it fires with the expected rate, but the state isn't changing.

I don't understand why the component is able to render correctly if the state isn't changing. Frankly, I have no idea what I'm doing wrong. Perhaps, someone helps me to clarify. Thanks in advance.

PS: I made a codesanbox with the example https://codesandbox.io/s/xenodochial-jepsen-nfxv6

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the `update` function returned from `useSquare` is a closure and the value of `x` and `y` inside it never change, thus the condition of `x <= 0 || x >= WIDTH` and `y <= 0 || y >= HEIGHT` are never true. Here is an example of closure:

```js
let x = 1;

function update(y) {
  return function() {
    console.log(y); // always 1
  };
}
setInterval(update(x), 1000);
x = 2;
```

Closure related bugs are hard to be identified. While you can learn more about closures in various resources including [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures), you can use the `exhaustive-deps` linting rule in `eslint-plugin-react-hooks` package to make sure your dependencies array specified in hooks are specified correctly and prevent potential bugs. [React docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html#tip-optimizing-performance-by-skipping-effects) (Such rule is enabled by default in CodeSandbox.)

But before that, let's simplify the task to find a better way to tackle the problem. Let's say there is a state `x` that will keep incrementing by 3 until it hits 20. Then it will keep decrementing by the same value until it hits 0.

In this case, we use +1/-1 to represent the direction of increment/decrement. Since this direction changes shouldn't trigger a re-render, we don't have to store it as a state variable. Instead, we store it as ref since we want to access its latest value when computing the new `x`. To detect if `x` hits the limits, we set up a `useEffect` hook. The full implementation would be:

```
import React, { useState, useRef, useEffect } from "react";
const MAX = 20;
const RATE = 3;

function App() {
  let [x, setX] = useState(0);
  const direction = useRef(1);
  useEffect(() => {
    const id = setInterval(() => {
      setX(val => val + direction.current * RATE);
    }, 500);
    return () => clearInterval(id);
  }, []);
  useEffect(() => {
    if (x >= MAX) direction.current = -1;
    if (x <= 0) direction.current = 1;
  }, [x]);
  return <div>{x}</div>;
}
```

Back to your case, there are few places that should be updated and the main part is inside `useSquare`. Like the above example, we no longer store `vx` and `vy` as state. Instead, initialize them with `useRef`. Two `useEffect` hooks are also set up to change their values according to `x` and `y` values.

```
// useSquare.js    
import { useState, useRef, useEffect, useCallback } from "react";
import { WIDHT, HEIGHT } from "./settings";

export function useSquare(init_x, init_y) {
  let [x, set_x] = useState(init_x);
  let [y, set_y] = useState(init_y);
  let vx = useRef(10);
  let vy = useRef(-5);

  let update = useCallback(() => {
    set_x(prev_x => prev_x + vx.current);
    set_y(prev_y => prev_y + vy.current);
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (x >= WIDHT) vx.current = -10;
    if (x <= 0) vx.current = 10;
  }, [x]);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (y <= 0) vy.current = 5;
    if (y >= HEIGHT) vy.current = -5;
  }, [y]);

  useEffect(() => {
    let id;
    function cb() {
      update();
      id = requestAnimationFrame(cb);
    }
    cb();
    return () => cancelAnimationFrame(id);
  }, [update]);

  return { x, y };
}
```

And the `app.js` becomes:

```
function App() {
  let canvas = useRef();
  let square = useSquare(WIDHT / 2, HEIGHT / 2);
  return (
    <>
      <canvas ref={canvas} width={WIDHT} height={HEIGHT} />
      <Renderer.Provider value={() => canvas.current.getContext("2d")}>
        <Square {...square} />
      </Renderer.Provider>
    </>
  );
}
```

Notice I put wrap the update function with an `useCallback` hook so that it will not change with `x` and `y` values. I also put the animation function inside `useSquare` hook. If you move it back to `App.js`, make sure you set the dependencies array right.

Here is the updated sandbox:

[image: Edit state-is-unchanged-from-within-a-function-returned-by-a-hook]

Comment: You are right about how closure works, but it's not true in this case because he is using set new state by prev state `set_x(prev_x => prev_x + vx)`, so `prev_x` is always latest one. This example in offical docs will explain more: https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-faq.html#what-can-i-do-if-my-effect-dependencies-change-too-often

Comment: @TonyNguyen You are right about the functional update. But the update conditions `(x <= 0 || x >= WIDTH)` and `(y <= 0 || y >= HEIGHT)` are never true, which causes the result of "Square is moving, but it doesn't respond to collisions with the viewport borders.".

Answer (score 1):

**Answer1:** The problem is every time the `requestAnimationFrame` run and `square.update()` you are actual create new box. You need to clear your frame before drawing new one

```
import { useContext, useEffect } from "react";
import { Renderer } from "./ctx";

export function Square({ x, y }) {
  let getContext = useContext(Renderer);
  useEffect(() => {
    let ctx = getContext();
    // clear before drawing
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
    ctx.fillStyle = "#000";
    ctx.fillRect(x, y, 10, 10);
  }, [x, y]);
  return null;
}
```

Check the [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/misty-sky-rzqwo?file=/src/Squre.js:0-384) for visualisation

This is [a very good series](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yq2au9EfeRQ) I found online. Check it out

**Answer2:** `requestAnimationFrame` create a loop to call `square.update()`, that's why's you can see the dimensions changed

**Answer3:** You are updating state inside `Square` component by calling `set**`